# Como substituir valor hexadecimal em um arquivo binário?

Tags: c#, .net

Podem me dizer como substituir o valor Hex de um arquivo com C#? Exemplo: substituir `62 61 72` (`"bar"`) por `66 6F 6F` (`"foo"`).

Comment: Não pode transformar isso em string pra fazer um replace ?

Comment: Você está falando de um arquivo binário?

Comment: Sim, O arquivo é binário.

Comment: Não dá pra abrir como arquivo texto e fazer a alteração com o `replace`?

Comment: Sou iniciante em C#, tentei usar o BinaryWriter para editar mas não consegui.

Comment: Tem uma referência ao tamanho desses arquivos binários ?

Answer (score 4):

Você terá de fazer o processamento dos bytes manualmente no caso de um arquivo binário:

```
byte[] findBytes = { 0x62, 0x61, 0x72 };
byte[] replaceBytes = { 0x66, 0x6F, 0x6F };
List<byte> result;

using (var file = File.OpenRead(@"...origem..."))
{
    var allBytes = new byte[(int)file.Length];
    file.Read(allBytes, 0, (int)file.Length);
    result = new List<byte>(allBytes.Length);

    for (int itFile = 0; itFile < allBytes.Length; itFile++)
    {
        bool found = !findBytes
            .Where((t, i) => (i + itFile >= allBytes.Length)
                || (t != allBytes[i + itFile])).Any();

        if (found)
        {
            result.AddRange(replaceBytes);
            itFile += findBytes.Length - 1;
        }
        else
            result.Add(allBytes[itFile]);
    }
}

using (var file = File.Open(@"...destino...", FileMode.Create))
    file.Write(result.ToArray(), 0, result.Count);
```

Essa é uma implementação bem bruta... que lê todos os bytes da origem e faz todo o processamento em memória... no caso de arquivos muito longos, provavelmente terá que subdividir o arquivo e fazer a substituição parte a parte.

Answer (score 1):

Existe uma excelente explicação em um post do StackOverflow  original em inglês:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217732/how-to-edit-a-binary-files-hex-value-using-c-sharp

Tradução adaptada da parte importante:

Se você deseja simplesmente trocar os valores dos bytes no arquivo, a abordagem mais eficiente na minha opinião seria abrir o arquivo usando um FileStream, buscar a posição adequada, e substituir os bytes, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite)) {
    stream.Position = 0;
    stream.WriteByte(0x66);
    stream.WriteByte(0x6F);
    stream.WriteByte(0x6F);
}
```

Comment: Mas aí ele obrigatoriamente teria que saber a posição dos bytes que deseja substituir.

Answer (score -2):

Tenta assim:
Hex p/ Decimal:

```
Convert.ToInt64(hexValue, 16);
```

Decimal p/ Hexadecimal:

```
string.format("{0:x}", decValue);
```

Comment: Isso mostra como converter de decimal para hexadecimal, mas não responde a pergunta. Se puder acrescentar à resposta a parte de editar o arquivo, sua resposta será melhor aceita.

Comment: interpretei mau a pergunta dele. ;)